# Couldn't show textfield on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I added a text field in viewDidLoad but it did not show up on screen.

Here's .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
    UITextField *tfText;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *tfText;
@end
```

Here's .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    tfText.frame = CGRectMake(65, 100, 200, 50);
    tfText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];    
    [tfText setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    tfText.placeholder = @"Test";
    [tfText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:tfText]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems that you need to initialize the object... I mean

```
UITextField *newTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
self.tfText = newTextField;
//....
//all your code here
//....
[newTextField release];
```

And dont forget to release your instance on dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

D33pN16h7 is correct, you need to instantiate your object. However I would do it a little differently than described above, there is no reason to create a UITextField instance, and then set your instance to it.

self.tfText = [[UITextField alloc] init];

Comment: This is an issue because generates a memory leak, the "alloc init" increment the retain count in one, and the property setter (self.tfText") increments the retain count also, so the code that i show you is the correct way to instantiate the object. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITextField entered2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 125.0, 150.0, 25.0)]; 
[entered2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
entered2.text=@"Active";    
[self.view addSubview:entered2];
[entered2 release];
```